# Incrementing Cookie Value in Javascript Each Refresh

Tags: javascript, increment

I am having an issue where I want a value of my cookie to increase by 1 each time I load the page. Currently, I can get the value to go up by 1, but since the values variable is called at the beginning it continues to reset each visit.

```
var cName = "Cookie Value";
var cValue = 0, expDays = 10;
let cookies = document.cookie;
        
function buildCookie(cName, cValue, expDays) {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
}

function setToZero() {
    buildCookie(cName, cValue=0, expDays);
    console.log('Cookie set to 0');
}

function wholePackage() {
    if (cookies == null) {
        setToZero();
    } else {
        if (cValue >= 0) {
            cValue = cValue + 1;
            buildCookie(cName, cValue, expDays);
            console.log('Cookie to set to ' + cValue);
        }
    }
}

wholePackage()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you have a cookie, you should read `cValue` from it instead of using the default value. You also have to properly parse `document.cookie` to get the value from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. If you want to set cookie value for each time page loads, then the initial value should be 1. Not zero. So, it is not setToZero, it should be setToOne. So set initial ***cValue = 1***.
2. In the **wholePackage** function, you are checking if the cValue is *greater than or equal to 0*. If it's true you are setting the cookie to 0. Which is wrong in two way.
   a. cValue is always 0 at the beginning. So it can't get higher.
   b. Even somehow you manage to increase cValue (ex- using a database), it is still greater than 0 and making the cookie 0 again.

So, what you need is to check if the cookie exists. If cookie with the name cName exists it will be set to **old cookie + 1**. Otherwise set to zero.

3. You can't check cookie value with this code

```
cookies = document.cookie
```

Instead, write this function to check if cookie exists,

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
```

Then the wholePackage function will be like this,

```
let cookies = getCookie(cName);

function wholePackage() {
    
    if (cookies == null) {
        setToOne();
    } else {
            cValue = cookies + 1;
            buildCookie(cName, cValue, expDays);
            console.log('Cookie to set to ' + cValue);
        }
    }
}
```

4. In buildCookie function, you can't have parameters' name as same as your previously declared variable. That's bad. **cName**, **cValue** is already declared in the beginning.
5. You don't need expiry date as a parameter as you are creating them inside the function.

Here is the complete fixed code,

```
var cName = "Cookie Value";
var cValue = 1;

function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 

let cookies = getCookie(cName);
        
function buildCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
}

function setToOne() {
    buildCookie(cName, cValue);
    console.log('Cookie set to 1');
}

function wholePackage() {
    
    if (cookies == null) {
        setToOne();
    } else {
            cValue = cookies + 1;
            buildCookie(cName, cValue);
            console.log('Cookie to set to ' + cValue);
        }
    }
}


wholePackage()
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been incredibly helpful!

Comment: Check the code again, I fixed some more code in a recent edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're resetting the counter on each page load because you don't read the current stored value inside of `document.cookie`.

You should first read the current value and then increment by 1.

In order to read the current value of a property inside the `document.cookie` you could do something like this:

```
const prop = document.cookie.split("; ").map(prop => prop.split("=")).find(prop => prop[0] === cName)
if (prop) {
    console.log('Current counter:', prop[1])
}
```

The code is very naive, but it should give you a starting point.

If it's not clear please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, this put me on the right track!

Comment: I'm glad to helped you. Please consider to accept one of the answers as correct in order to help future people to find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In `wholePackage` methods you need to get value of cookie and convert it to number by below code:

```
+document.cookie.split("; ")[0].split("=")[1]
```

This is complete code:

```
var cName = "Cookie Value";
var cValue = 0, expDays = 10;
let cookies = document.cookie;

function buildCookie(cName, cValue, expDays) {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
}

function setToZero() {
    buildCookie(cName, cValue = 0, expDays);
    console.log('Cookie set to 0');
}

function wholePackage() {
    if (!cookies) {
        setToZero();
    } else {
        if (cValue >= 0) {
            cValue = +document.cookie.split("; ")[0].split("=")[1] + 1;
            buildCookie(cName, cValue, expDays);
            console.log('Cookie to set to ' + cValue);
        }
    }
}

wholePackage()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help! Is there a way that I should mark this solved?